# Use select query in function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have some questions about stored procedures.

Using `select` query inside the function is efficient or using `select` query in front end. Which is take `less time` and give the result is fast or if have any other way to use `select` query in efficient manner? Please help.

**EDIT**

We are using `postgresql-9.1`. I want clarify my doubts because in my office we are using select query's (Getting Results from backend) in front end for reports. Now we want to know which is better and efficent way for using select query is front end or stored procedure (back end).

Thank you

Comment: Nowhere near enough detail here. PostgreSQL version? (I'm sure I've reminded you to always include your Pg version before). Queries? Table sizes? Client/server connection info?

Comment: @CraigRinger postgresql-9.1. I want clarify my doubts because in my office we are using select query's  in front end for reports. Now we want to know which is better and efficent way for using select query is front end or stored procedure (back end)

Comment: The query *always* runs in the server backend. If you need to (a) run the query and (b) send the results to the client, then all a stored proc gains you is a little bit of startup overhead.

Comment: @CraigRinger this is true only from a performance point of view.  Just for the sake of nitpicking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on what the data is, what you're doing with the data, what the bandwidth between client and server is, what stored procedure language you're using, etc.

Test it and see. You can:

- Use the `psql` `\timing` command to get the final execution time including results transfer from the client perspective;
- Use `log_min_duration_statement = 0` in `postgresql.conf` and in your `psql` client run `SET client_min_messages = INFO` to see the messages or examine the logs. This will show you how long the statements took to run server-side.
- Use `explain` and `explain analyze` to examine query plans and execution details
- Use the `auto_explain` contrib module to collect detailed data, optoinally including execution times inside stored functions.